# Looping with switchs?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, break

What I am trying to do is create a rental car CALCULATOR. that has pre-loaded daily fees and fuel charges for three different cars. There is a 6% sales tax I'm trying to add to everything. The input of the user determines the total and etc..

Full project detailed: [https://www.scribd.com/document/392038034/Bob-s-Car-Rental-Intermediate-pdf]

{MY CODE CURRENTLY}

```
package tests;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String []args){
    int days, cus, carType, fuel, count=0;
    double dailyFee=0, nonTaxTotal=0, total=0, fullTotal=0, fuelcharge=0, taxes=0, avrg=0, Fullcharge=0;
    boolean checkRunOrQuit = false, chooseTypeVehicle = false, numberOfDAysChosen = false, fuellevel = false, reset=true;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
while(!reset); 

    while ( !checkRunOrQuit ) {
        System.out.print("Press 1 to enter Rental Calculator or else press 0 to quit\n");
        System.out.println("Please only enter 1 or 0. Also, please only enter number(s) not letter(s)");
        try {
            cus=in.nextInt();
            switch ( cus ) {
                case 0: System.out.print("End of application\n");
                        System.out.println("Count of customers: " + count);
                        System.out.printf("Total fuel charges $ %.2f \n", Fullcharge);
                        System.out.printf("Total taxes collected: $ %.2f \n", taxes);
                        System.out.printf("Total of the Day: $ %.2f \n", fullTotal);
                        System.out.printf("The average bill was: $ %.2f \n", avrg);
                        System.exit(0);
                break;
                case 1: checkRunOrQuit = true;
                break;
                default:
                        System.out.println("Number must be either 1 or 0");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry: ");
            in.next();
        }
    }

     while( !chooseTypeVehicle ) {

        System.out.print("What vehical would you like to rent?\n");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for an economy car");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for a sedan car");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 for an SUV");

        try {
            carType = in.nextInt();
            chooseTypeVehicle = true;
            switch ( carType ) {
                case 1: dailyFee = 31.76;
                count++;
                break;
                case 2: dailyFee = 40.32;
                count++;
                break;
                case 3: dailyFee = 47.56;
                count++;
                break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("Number must be 1-3\n");
                    chooseTypeVehicle = false;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
            in.next();
        }
    }

    while ( !fuellevel ) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Is the fuel empty?\n");
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 for yes.");
            System.out.println("Please enter 2 for no.");
            fuel = in.nextInt();
            if (fuel <= 0 |fuel > 2.1) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a 1 or 2\n");
            } else {
                fuellevel = true;
                switch ( fuel ) {
                case 1: fuelcharge = 40.00;
                fuelcharge+=Fullcharge;
                break;
                case 2: fuelcharge = 0.00;
                break;
                }
            }} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
                in.next();
            }
        }

    while ( !numberOfDAysChosen ) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Please enter the number of days rented. (Example; 3) : ");
            days = in.nextInt();
            if (days <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Number of days must be more than zero");
            } else {
                nonTaxTotal = (dailyFee * days);
                nonTaxTotal = (nonTaxTotal + fuelcharge);
                total = (nonTaxTotal * 1.06);
                taxes = (total - nonTaxTotal);
                avrg = ( total/count );
                fullTotal+=total;
                numberOfDAysChosen = true;
            }
        } catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
            in.next();
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Rental rate: $%.2f \n", dailyFee);
    System.out.printf("Total fuel charge: $%.2f \n", fuelcharge);
    System.out.printf("Subtotal: $%.2f \n", nonTaxTotal);
    System.out.printf("Taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
    System.out.printf("Total: $%.2f \n", fullTotal);

    System.out.print("Press 1 to enter Rental Calculator or else press 0 to quit\n");
    System.out.println("Please only enter 1 or 0. Also, please only enter number(s) not letter(s)");
    try {
        cus=in.nextInt();
        switch ( cus ) {
            case 0: System.out.print("End of application. \n");
                    System.out.println("Count of customers: " + count);
                    System.out.printf("Total fuel charges $ %.2f \n", Fullcharge);
                    System.out.printf("Total taxes collected: $ %.2f \n", taxes);
                    System.out.printf("Total of the Day: $ %.2f \n", fullTotal);
                    System.out.printf("The average bill was: $ %.2f \n", avrg);
                    System.exit(0);
            break;
            case 1: checkRunOrQuit = true;
            break;
            default:
                    System.out.println("Number must be either 1 or 0");
                    break;
        }} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry: ");
            in.next();
    }


    in.close();
    System.out.printf("Rental rate: $%.2f \n", dailyFee);
    System.out.printf("Total fuel charge: $%.2f \n", fuelcharge);
    System.out.printf("Subtotal: $%.2f \n", nonTaxTotal);
    System.out.printf("Total: $%.2f \n", fullTotal);
    System.out.printf("Taxes: $%.2f ", taxes);


    }

}
```

1. After inputing the days rented I wanted the user to be promted if they would like to calculate another car. When i try to label and break it, I can not succsful get the code to resume from the start (asking Car Type)??

Comment: `while(!reset); ` - not correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Car Rental Calculator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075883/creating-a-car-rental-calculator)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't know what to do I've been trying to fix this for hours now. :(

Comment: Yeah, but have tried doing what people have suggested?  Read my first comment in this POST - correct it - now what?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, I've tried my hardest to thoroughly read every comment. After removing `while(!reset);` I still have the same issues. I do not understand methods enough to re-write my entire program without creating more errors. I do not obviously understand loops to the fullest. I legit do not know what to do without creating more problems. I am not understanding breaks. Yes, I have tried. I have not left my computer, java eclipse or this website since my first post. I am trying.

Comment: There are two types of `breaks` - one is used in a switch and prevents the next case from being entered into.  The other break is for a loop and it terminates (breaks out) of that loop.  Now what?

Comment: replace `while(!reset);` with `while(!reset) {` and add a `}`  after `System.out.printf("Taxes: $%.2f ", taxes);`

Comment: also set `reset = false`

Comment: @LonelyCpp thank you for taking a jab at it. so when you say after `System.out.printf("Taxes: $%.2f ", taxes);` there are two so I went with the very end one in my code. anyway, this still did not fix the issue I'm having of not being able to do multiple calculations. thanks again tho, any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must really think of how to solve the problem before writing it mate. The code you've written is very procedural and poorly written. You sould really look into how to use control statements in java.

Try this -

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int days, cus, carType, fuel, count = 0;
        double dailyFee = 0, nonTaxTotal = 0, total = 0, fullTotal = 0, fuelcharge = 0, taxes = 0, avrg = 0, Fullcharge = 0;
        boolean checkRunOrQuit = false, chooseTypeVehicle = false, numberOfDAysChosen = false, fuellevel = false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {

            while (!checkRunOrQuit) {
                System.out.print("Press 1 to enter Rental Calculator or else press 0 to quit\n");
                System.out.println("Please only enter 1 or 0. Also, please only enter number(s) not letter(s)");
                try {
                    cus = in.nextInt();
                    switch (cus) {
                        case 0:
                            System.out.print("End of application\n");
                            System.out.println("Count of customers: " + count);
                            System.out.printf("Total fuel charges $ %.2f \n", Fullcharge);
                            System.out.printf("Total taxes collected: $ %.2f \n", taxes);
                            System.out.printf("Total of the Day: $ %.2f \n", fullTotal);
                            System.out.printf("The average bill was: $ %.2f \n", avrg);
                            System.exit(0);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            checkRunOrQuit = true;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Number must be either 1 or 0");
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry: ");
                    in.next();
                }
            }

            checkRunOrQuit = false;

            while (!chooseTypeVehicle) {

                System.out.print("What vehical would you like to rent?\n");
                System.out.println("Enter 1 for an economy car");
                System.out.println("Enter 2 for a sedan car");
                System.out.println("Enter 3 for an SUV");

                try {
                    carType = in.nextInt();
                    chooseTypeVehicle = true;
                    switch (carType) {
                        case 1:
                            dailyFee = 31.76;
                            count++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dailyFee = 40.32;
                            count++;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            dailyFee = 47.56;
                            count++;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.print("Number must be 1-3\n");
                            chooseTypeVehicle = false;
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
                    in.next();
                }
            }

            chooseTypeVehicle = false;

            while (!fuellevel) {
                try {
                    System.out.print("Is the fuel empty?\n");
                    System.out.println("Please enter 1 for yes.");
                    System.out.println("Please enter 2 for no.");
                    fuel = in.nextInt();
                    if (fuel <= 0 | fuel > 2.1) {
                        System.out.print("Please enter a 1 or 2\n");
                    } else {
                        fuellevel = true;
                        switch (fuel) {
                            case 1:
                                fuelcharge = 40.00;
                                fuelcharge += Fullcharge;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                fuelcharge = 0.00;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
                    in.next();
                }
            }

            fuellevel = false;

            while (!numberOfDAysChosen) {
                try {
                    System.out.print("Please enter the number of days rented. (Example; 3) : ");
                    days = in.nextInt();
                    if (days <= 0) {
                        System.out.println("Number of days must be more than zero");
                    } else {
                        nonTaxTotal = (dailyFee * days);
                        nonTaxTotal = (nonTaxTotal + fuelcharge);
                        total = (nonTaxTotal * 1.06);
                        taxes = (total - nonTaxTotal);
                        avrg = (total / count);
                        fullTotal += total;
                        numberOfDAysChosen = true;
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Answer must be a number");
                    in.next();
                }
            }

            numberOfDAysChosen = false;

            System.out.printf("Rental rate: $%.2f \n", dailyFee);
            System.out.printf("Total fuel charge: $%.2f \n", fuelcharge);
            System.out.printf("Subtotal: $%.2f \n", nonTaxTotal);
            System.out.printf("Taxes: $%.2f \n", taxes);
            System.out.printf("Total: $%.2f \n", fullTotal);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes looking at yours and comparing it to mine. I would say that my hands on skills are not up to par for this project at least. With anything in the future, I am going to try to read the chapters better (my teacher gives me), as well as reviewing some of the chapters we have already covered. Would you have any recommendations for what i should focus on?  Anyway, Thank you for your help. this did fix my issue. Please let me know if I can do anything more than upvote and checkmark.